# Getting result in jSON

Tags: php, ajax, json

I am having 3 pages, that deals with Ajax, step1.php, step2.php and step3.php:

step1.php

```
<head>

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "step2.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {

    } // end function
}); // end ajax  
</head>
<body>
<?php
// PHP codes
?>
```

step2.php

```
<head>
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "step3.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data) {

    } // end function
}); // end ajax  
</head>
<body>
<?php
$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']               = Isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])      ? strip_tags($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) : $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] = Null;

    if(!$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])
    {
         require_once '../Error/404.php';
    }
    else
    {

        $taken_time_start = time();

$num    = Isset($_POST['num'])      ? trim(intval(abs($_POST['num'])))      : $num      = Null;
$id_ism = Isset($_POST['id_ism'])   ? trim(intval(abs($_POST['id_ism'])))   : $id_ism   = Null;
$Start = Isset($_POST['Start'])   ? trim(intval(abs($_POST['Start'])))   : $Start   = Null;
$End = Isset($_POST['End'])   ? trim(intval(abs($_POST['End'])))   : $End   = Null;

$nums = $End - $Start;

if($nums < 2) {
//    echo 'please choose at least 3 s<br />';
$hideButton = 'false'; // hide show  button
} else {

$cSel = 'SELECT * FROM results WHERE s_ism = "'.$id_ism.'"';
//echo $aSel.'<br />';
$cReq = $connexion->query($cSel);
$cRes = $cReq->fetchAll();

if($cRes){
echo 'yes there is';
} else {
echo 'no';  
}
}
    } // end HTTP_REQUEST
```

and so on, my question is: can I get the result of step2.php in step1.php treatment using jSON?

Thanks everybody

Comment: It's confusing, you're talking about PHP files, but it is Javascript code. Maybe you could show us the PHP part of the code at least ? Or maybe you have just no idea how to proceed with PHP ?

Comment: I edited my codes, I am focussing on JS side

Comment: use PHP $_SESSION to hold the data in `$_SESSION['step1']` and show in any step you want, or you can use jquery form wizard plugin to do multi-step form

Comment: and how about the code between head in step2.php? because step2.php will call again step3.php

Comment: if not in json, how can I proceed as the aboved code **CODE EDITED**